# How to minimize equation over a list of values?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I tried to do something like `Minimize[x+y, {x,y} ∈ {2,3,4,5}]` but that doesn't work. How could I minimize an expression where I restrict the inputs to values from a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Minimize[{x + y, AnyTrue[{2, 3, 4, 5}, EqualTo[x]], 
  AnyTrue[{2, 3, 4, 5}, EqualTo[y]]}, {x, y}]
```

`{4, {x -> 2, y -> 2}}`

Comment: Thanks, this works the way I wanted. This is not particularly important, but I tried replacing `AnyTrue[{2, 3, 4, 5}, EqualTo[x]]` to `MemberQ[{2, 3, 4, 5}, x]` but that didn't work. I thought it would be easier to remember. Do you know why it didn't work?

Comment: `Minimize[x + y, {x, y} ∈ImplicitRegion[(x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5) && (y == 2 ||y == 3 || y == 4 || y == 5), {x, y}]]
` another  way that is easy understand .

Comment: `Minimize[{x + y, Or @@ Thread[ConstantArray[x, 4] == {2, 3, 4, 5}], 
  Or @@ Thread[ConstantArray[y, 4] == {2, 3, 4, 5}]}, {x, y}]`

Answer (score 2):

One way.

```
x = Range[2, 5]
y = Range[2, 5]

Min[x + y]
(*4*)
```

Comment: That works for finding the minimum value, but Minimize also shows you the values of x and y that were used to generate the minimum value.

Answer (score 1):

For those who use older versions of MMA, where `AnyTrue`  is not implemented:

```
cond = Or @@ # & /@ And @@ Outer[Equal, {x, y}, {2, 3, 4, 5}]

(*   (x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5) && 
     (y == 2 || y == 3 || y == 4 || y == 5)   *)

Minimize[{x + y, cond}, {x, y}]

(*   {4, {x -> 2, y -> 2}}   *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option,

```
xyVals = Tuples[ {Range[2, 5, 1], Range[2, 5, 1] }]
fxyVals = Apply[#1 + #2 &, xyVals, {1}]
Min[fxyVals]
(*4*)
```